# Salesforce Apex Batch Class - SLA Logic Issue

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have a Salesforce Apex batch class named LeadNotificationBatch that is intended to enforce an SLA (Service Level Agreement) requiring lead owners to take action on leads within 24 business hours. The SLA should exclude weekends (Saturday and Sunday) and should apply to all leads except those in 'Closed - Converted' and 'Closed - Not Converted' statuses.

**SLA Logic Requirements:**

1. For leads with statuses other than 'Closed - Converted' and 'Closed

   - Not Converted': Lead owners must take action within 24 business hours. Business hours are from Monday to Friday, excluding weekends(Saturday and Sunday). If a lead is created on a Friday, the SLA
     should extend to the following Monday, skipping the weekend.

**Code Issue:**
I've implemented the SLA logic in the execute method of the LeadNotificationBatch class, but I'm encountering issues, and the SLA is not being enforced as expected:

**Relevant Code (Simplified):**

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> leads) {
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

for (Lead l : leads) {
    DateTime createdDate = l.CreatedDate;
    DateTime lastModifiedDate = l.LastModifiedDate;
    Integer daysToAdd = 0;

    // Check if the lead was created on a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
    if (createdDate.format('E') == 'Sat') {
        daysToAdd = 2; // Add 2 days to reach Monday
    } else if (createdDate.format('E') == 'Sun') {
        daysToAdd = 1; // Add 1 day to reach Monday
    }

    createdDate = createdDate.addDays(daysToAdd);
    createdDate = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(createdDate.year(), createdDate.month(), createdDate.day(), 0, 0, 0); // Set time to 00:00:00

    // Check if the lead's status is 'New'
    if (l.Status == 'New') {
        // Calculate the elapsed business minutes only on weekdays
        Long elapsedBusinessMinutes = 0;
        
        while (createdDate < now) {
            if (createdDate.format('E') != 'Sat' && createdDate.format('E') != 'Sun') {
                elapsedBusinessMinutes += BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, createdDate, createdDate.addMinutes(60)) / 1000 / 60;
            }

            createdDate = createdDate.addMinutes(60); // Move forward by 1 hour
        }

        // Check if it's been more than 24 hours since creation
        if (elapsedBusinessMinutes >= 1440) {
            // Add lead to send notifications
            // notification logic here.
        }
    } else {
        // Check if it's been more than 24 hours since last modification, excluding weekends
        if (lastModifiedDate != null && now - lastModifiedDate > (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
            // Add lead to send notifications
            // notification logic here.
        }
    }
}}
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly implement the SLA logic in the execute method to ensure that lead owners take action within 24 business hours, excluding weekends, and that it applies to the specified lead statuses. Any help would be greatly appreciated.